# How to prevent resume from sleep/suspend on lid open?

Tags: laptop, suspend, suspend-resume

I've got pretty much the same problem as [this old 2006 thread on the **Ubuntu forums**](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=293883): my old laptop's lid is a bit shaky, which causes the computer to wakeup/suspend if I just touch it the wrong way (e.g. lifting it up to move it).

Back then, the fix (see link) was to have a startup script disable LID in /proc/acpi/wakeup every time the computer boots. I'm wondering if there's a better, less hacky, solution?

Comment: Did they get rid `/proc/acpi/wakeup` in Maverick? It still exists on my Lucid system, and I don't see why it shouldn't work.

Comment: Nope it's still here, so the solution from 2006 still works. It's just a bit of a hassle to maintain.

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 4):

Its no less hacky, but you can simplify the solution by adding `echo "LID " > /proc/acpi/wakeup` to the /etc/rc.local file. This way you don't have to create a startup script.

Comment: permissin denied even with sudo :(

Answer (score 2):

What about changing it to Blank screen when laptop lid is closed. This is way you will not get suspended.

System-->Preferences-->PowerManagement

Comment: Nope... this keeps the laptop running when I close the lid, but if I suspend it manually before that, it still wakes up when I open the lid. The idea is to prevent the laptop from waking up when the lid moves a bit, not preventing it from going to sleep.