# My Lenovo W500 resumes from suspend prematurely

Tags: power-management, suspend, thinkpad, acpi

In both Ubuntu 10.04 and 12.04, a perfectly happy sleeping laptop is woken when moved.  Either the HD-shock detection, the trackpad or a sloppy key will wake it when the lid is closed.

To test this I suspended the computer and left it for 5-10 minutes where it slept nicely with the lid open.  Then pressing the Fn-key would wake it in 12.04.  In sleep mode with the lid closed, moving the laptop wakes it.  Sometimes it immediately goes back to sleep, but not always.  It's a laptop and I put it in a bag to carry to and from work, so being asleep is kind of important.

I'm hoping someone can suggest a way to debug.

Thanks!

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my hinge for the display was weak or loose and the open lid event was causing it to resume.  I disabled it with this:

[How to prevent resume from sleep/suspend on lid open?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8056/how-to-prevent-resume-from-sleep-suspend-on-lid-open)