# Automatic Power On After Suspend

Tags: power-management, suspend

With every laptop I've had which had Ubuntu installed on it, first my Acer Aspire One and then my Dell Inspiron 15R, when I close it, it goes into suspend mode. When I open it, it attempts to power back up. Is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

It's normal. You can disable the suspend on close in gnome power manager (or xfce power manager). [See this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid).

I haven't seen an option to disable the power-on on lid open function, however apparently it can be done by editing the `/proc/acpi/wakeup` file and setting the `LID` to `*disabled` as [seen here](https://askubuntu.com/a/22497/42823).